# Table pg_statistic_ext_data is not accessible on Postgres (Amazon RDS)

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Table `pg_statistic_ext_data` can not be accessed on Amazon RDS Postgres, but is needed to understand the extended statistics of the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer from AWS Support:

> Unfortunately access to `pg_statistic_ext_data` is not provided in Amazon RDS, however `pg_stats_ext` is a publicly readable view on `pg_statistic_ext_data` that only exposes information about those tables and columns that are readable by the current user. I recommend you to use `pg_stats_ext` which also gives the output in a better readable format.
>
> The view `pg_stats_ext` provides access to the information stored in the `pg_statistic_ext` and `pg_statistic_ext_data` catalogs. This view allows access only to rows of `pg_statistic_ext` and `pg_statistic_ext_data` that correspond to tables the user has permission to read, and therefore it is safe to allow public read access to this view.
>
> `pg_stats_ext` is also designed to present the information in a more readable format than the underlying catalogs — at the cost that its schema must be extended whenever new types of extended statistics are added to pg_statistic_ext.